# facing issue DataSourceId parameter in the CreateDataSource method in quickSight in JAVA sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, amazon-quicksight

So I am using quick sight java SDK for integrating s3 with quicksight, and for that, I am using CreateDataSource.so while using this method, I have to pass one parameter in this method **DataSourceId**. The description of this parameter in the AWS documentation is like "An ID for the data source. This ID is unique per AWS Region for each AWS account," and I do not know how to get this.i to have to get this parameter programmatically. Type of this parameter is String

```
getClient().createDataSource(new CreateDataSourceRequest().withDataSourceId("DataSourceID").withAwsAccountId("AWS ACCOUNT").withName("display name of data soure").withType(DataSourceType.S3));
```

getClient is a client for using quicksight API

and yeah for the integration of s3 and quicksight I can not do this through AWS console I have to do this programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know how to get this.i to have to get this parameter programmatically

This is something that you set yourself, for example:

```
DataSourceId = "my-first-test-data-source-id"
```